# Is it possible to have the menu bar stay in its place even when moving screens?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I had just reset my whole MacBook and while I was reconfiguring, I'd decided to keep the menu bar visible as all time (was kept hidden before). Right now, whenever I'm switching screens (3 finger swipe), the menu bar will then follows the screen and moves. I think this is redundant since all the menu bar needs to change is just the application you're currently focusing on.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2 (When swiping to left)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Apple designed this intentionally.

You would need a different window manager to allow the chrome to operate differently than the content. Mission control has this baked into the animation code with custom animation curves to ease in and out of this transition.